AWS S3 Object Metadata Not Returning Despite Being Set
I'm creating a Web service using AWS S3 in Node, where users upload files that are supposed to have an author metadata tag. When a user uploads, the following kind of pre-signed URL is created to upload the file securely on the client-side, with sensitive values redacted (due to the limitations of my hosting service, full server-side uploading is not an option):
https://my-website.s3.tebi.io/category/subcategory/file_name.wav?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=<redacted>&X-Amz-Date=<redacted>&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=<redacted>&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-amz-meta-author=John%20Doe&x-id=PutObject

Then the file finishes uploading by sending a Fetch request with the above signedURL:
fetch(signedURL, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        "Content-Length": new Blob([file]).size
    },
    body: new Blob([file], { type: mimeType })
})
.then(response => {
    if(response.ok) fileUploaded = true;
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));

I can successfully view the uploaded files via ListObjectsV2Command, but when I try to view the metadata via HeadObjectCommand on the object in the bucket, x-amz-meta-author is nowhere to be found (while the other metadata appears exactly as expected, including the file size):
{
  data: {
    '$metadata': {
      httpStatusCode: 200,
      requestId: '<redacted>',
      extendedRequestId: 'node-usw-2',
      cfId: undefined,
      attempts: 1,
      totalRetryDelay: 0
    },
    AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
    LastModified: <redacted>,
    ContentLength: 66528,
    ETag: '"<redacted>"',
    CacheControl: 'no-cache',
    ContentType: 'audio/flac',
    Metadata: {}
  }
}

I have double-checked to make sure x-amz-meta-author is in the ExposedHeader list to avoid CORS issues. Any ideas for what I'm missing? I'm happy to provide additional details as needed. Thanks in advance!

So the PUT was successful? Could you retry but add the x-amz-meta-author=John%20Doe etc. metadata to the HTTP headers that you pass to fetch.

Looks like you've set up everything correctly for uploading the file with the x-amz-meta-author metadata. Issue might be related to how the metadata is being handled during the upload process.

The response from @jarmod was right on the money! Adding x-amz-meta-author to the headers for the PUT request allowed the data to be available in the HeadObjectCommand:
fetch(signedURL, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        "Content-Length": new Blob([file]).size
        "x-amz-meta-author": "John Doe"
    },
    body: new Blob([file], { type: mimeType })
})
.then(response => {
    if(response.ok) fileUploaded = true;
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));

{
  data: {
    '$metadata': {
      httpStatusCode: 200,
      requestId: '<redacted>',
      extendedRequestId: 'node-usw-2',
      cfId: undefined,
      attempts: 1,
      totalRetryDelay: 0
    },
    AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
    LastModified: <redacted>,
    ContentLength: 66528,
    ETag: '"<redacted>"',
    CacheControl: 'no-cache',
    ContentType: 'audio/flac',
    Metadata: { author: 'John Doe' }
  }
}

